# Cypher : Union between queries, with an initial node retrieval

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to write a Cypher query which is kind of a "union" query, basically something like :

```
MATCH (myNodeUsedInAllSubQueries)
WITH myNodeUsedInAllSubQueries
MATCH (a)-[...]->(myNodeUsedInAllSubQueries)
RETURN a
UNION
MATCH (b)-[...]->(myNodeUsedInAllSubQueries)
RETURN b
...
```

I want to match `(myNodeUsedInAllSubQueries)` **once** at the beginning because this node is used in all subqueries.
Of course, the retrieval of this node in my example is not just as simple as this (it involves relationships and a `WHERE` clause, but I'll keep it simple here).

I'll try to explain this with a simple example and what I've tried so far.

## Example

Graphically, the graph structure is the following :

```
(John: Person) ----------[LIKES]----------> (pizza: Food)
                                               ^
        (Developers: Group) ------[LIKES]------┘ 

(Jim: Person) --[BELONGS_TO]--> (Business: Group) --[LIKES]--> (apple: Food)
```

The example is accessible [here in Neo4J console](http://console.neo4j.org/r/o9n15y). The import script is here (in case you want to reproduce the issue locally) :

```
CREATE (john: Person{name: "John"});
CREATE (jim: Person{name: "Jim"});

CREATE (devs: Group{name: "Developers"});
CREATE (business: Group{name: "Business"});

CREATE (pizza: Food{name: "pizza"});
CREATE (apple: Food{name: "apple"});

MATCH (john: Person{name: "John"}), (pizza: Food{name: "pizza"})
CREATE (john)-[:LIKES]->(pizza);

MATCH (jim: Person{name: "Jim"}), (business: Group{name: "Business"})
CREATE (jim)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(business);

MATCH (devs: Group{name: "Developers"}), (pizza: Food{name: "pizza"})
CREATE (devs)-[:LIKES]->(pizza);

MATCH (business: Group{name: "Business"}), (apple: Food{name: "apple"})
CREATE (business)-[:LIKES]->(apple);
```

For that particular example, my question is : how to retrieve all `Person` nodes who likes pizza? Knowing that :

- A `Person` can like `Food` (direct relation)
- A `Group` can like `Food`, and transitively if person `A` `BELONGS_TO` a group,
  he `LIKES` also the food that the group `LIKES` (but there is **no direct relation**
  between `Person` and `Food` in that case)

I'd also like to retrieve the `pizza` node once. As I said in introduction, in my real example, the retrieval of `pizza` could be quite complicated, so I don't want to duplicate the `MATCH` in each case.

### What I've tried

#### Using `UNION`

```
MATCH (pizza: Food{name: "pizza"})
WITH pizza
MATCH (p: Person)-[:LIKES]->(pizza)
RETURN p
UNION
MATCH (p: Person)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(g: Group)-[:LIKES]->(pizza)
RETURN p
```

This query returns surprinsingly 2 nodes : `John` and `Jim`. After investigating, I have understood that
this is because `(pizza)` in the 2nd `UNION` clause does not refer to the `pizza` node
returned by the first `MATCH`, but rather any node. We can confirm that by running :

```
MATCH (pizza: Food{name: "pizza"})
WITH pizza
MATCH (p: Person)-[:LIKES]->(pizza)
RETURN p
UNION
MATCH (p: Person)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(g: Group)-[:LIKES]->(anything)
WHERE anything = pizza
RETURN p
```

This returns an error :

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Variable `pizza` not defined (line 7, column 18 (offset: 184))
"WHERE anything = pizza"
```

, validating the fact that `pizza` node is not propagated to the second `MATCH`.

#### Using `WITH` and `COLLECT`

This fixes the problem of the `pizza` node that cannot be passed from the first `MATCH` to the 3nd `MATCH`.

```
MATCH (pizza: Food{name: "pizza"})
WITH pizza
MATCH (p: Person)-[:LIKES]->(pizza)
WITH pizza, COLLECT(p) AS people
MATCH (p: Person)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(g: Group)-[:LIKES]->(pizza)
RETURN people + COLLECT(p) AS people
```

But this query does not return anything : this is because the 3nd `MATCH` does not return anything
(there are no `Person` in a `Group` that `LIKES` `pizza`).

If I add a `Person` in the `Developers` `Group` :

```
MATCH (devs: Group{name: "Developers"})
CREATE (emma: Person{name: "Emma"})-[:BELONGS_TO]->(devs)
```

The previous query returns successfully John and Emma because the last `MATCH` returns **at least** one `Person`.
But in my case, it is possible that this `MATCH` does not return anything, so that does not work.

I hope this example is simple and clear. In this case, the query I'm looking for should return only John, because he's the only `Person` here who likes `pizza`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternate to cybersam's answer, if your graph structure is such that `MATCH (p:Person)-[:BELONGS_TO|LIKES*..2]->(food:Food)` won't work (for example if you're working on a graph where people can like each other, and you don't want to return a person who likes another person who likes pizza, which would adhere to your pattern), you can use a `0..1` length relationship to represent an optional step in the pattern:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:BELONGS_TO*0..1]->()-[:LIKES]->(food:Food)
WHERE food.name = "pizza"
RETURN COLLECT(p) AS people;
```

This allows matching to both of these patterns at the same time:

`(p:Person)-[:LIKES]->(food:Food)`

and

`(p:Person)-[:BELONGS_TO]->()-[:LIKES]->(food:Food)`

I've written up a [knowledge base article](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/alternatives-to-union-queries/) on this approach.

Comment: Thanks, this works for the example I have provided. I have already read your article, but rewriting `UNION` queries is not always as simple. In my real world example, I have more that two `UNION` "subqueries", and representing this with a single `MATCH` is very tedious. Is it possible to write an union directly in a `MATCH` clause? Something like : `MATCH [...] OR [...] WHERE food.name = "pizza" ...`?

Comment: Sorry, that approach isn't possible at this time. For more complex cases, you may truly need a UNION, or you can use [other approaches](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/post-union-processing/), especially if you need to do additional work with the unioned results.

Comment: I see, then I'll try to rewrite my query with your suggestions, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

[UPDATED]

This should work for your simple use case:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:BELONGS_TO|LIKES*..2]->(food:Food {name:"pizza"})
RETURN food, COLLECT(p) AS people;
```

Comment: Thanks, that should be `MATCH (p:Person)-[:BELONGS_TO|LIKES*..2]->(food:Food{name: "pizza"})` here because I would like to retrieve only people who likes pizza.

Comment: My answer has been adjusted.